# how to write laravel code in css to change value of property

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

```
background-color: #55ce63;
color: #fff;
content:<? {{__('trans.On')}} ?>;
padding-right: 14px
```

this code css in header of blade how to write laravel code in css  to change

Comment: `content: '{{ __('trans.On') }}';`. This will only work on a blade file.

Comment: what can i do for  translate value off css

Comment: what do you mean by *translate value off css* ?

Comment: You cannot use php/blade in your css file, You can use css variables or style in your blade layout

Comment: You can provide translations in the lang folder, not translate arbitrary strings

Answer (score 2):

You can't use php or blade in your css file, but you can set a css variable in your .blade.php file as a style attribute:

```
style="--content-on: '{{ __('trans.On') }}';"
```

And use that variable in your css file:

```
content: var(--content-on);
```

Comment: @AbdelkawySalah If this answer solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it when you can so it can be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using Laravel variables in the CSS file.

Make your style which you want to style with variables inline style in your blade page.

You can try something like this:

```
style="color:{{{ $var_name }}}"
```